# What is this device called

Tags: led, power

Hey I took apart a joystick and I found some pretty neat parts. I found multiple of these knobs; I think that's what they're called.

**Characteristics of Component**

1. Turns
2. Three wires

**Picture **

[image: picture of component]

**My question(s)**

1. What is this switch called?
2. How do I connect it to an LED(Connect it in general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer).
2. That depends entirely on what you want the circuit to do.

Read up on potentiometers, what they are and how they work. That will tell you how, and if, you connect it to your LED.

Comment: Cool I always wanted one of those, can it dem an LED?

Comment: Yes. It can also burn a LED out. Read up on LEDs to understand why. Hint: LEDs are current driven, not voltage driven. Now that you know what the component is called, Google is your friend. Happy reading!

Comment: Lol. You can find "one of those" in any electronic junk or buy for few cents in a store. You can dim a LED with it, but it is not the most efficient way.

Comment: I don't think it's quite fair to say for a few cents. It's at _least_ a few dozen cents.

Comment: Ok cool, thinks for your thoughts.

Comment: This can certainly be used for motors right?

Comment: I will read more on it later

Comment: If you use it directly on a motor it will let free the magic smoke. It is not a high current device by any means.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not 100% sure since it could be some rudimentary rotery encoder, it's almost certainly a [potentiometer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer). The way you connect it to an led depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Easy way to tell is that most rotary encoders you can turn continuously, and almost all potentiometers you can only turn through about one full rotation (some more than one, but almost all of them will hit an end stop on their rotation)

Comment: Ok cool, this one does stop.